# Basic Steps required to get from a node js that outputs mulitple numbers to a website that shows them live in a table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, websocket

I have been working on a little site project for a while where I **scrape** numbers from different websites. A node.js collects them, and I got to the point where I can output them comfortably.
As per title, and since I am a total noob, what is the most basic framework to get them shown live on mywebsite.com? I have been messing around with Redis, socket.io, ajax and more, but none of that seemed to solve the issue. My dream would be a template for a table where the cells are my variables, and a 10 click process to hook that up to my website.
Any help what so ever would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use socket.io or any websocket framework that suits for you. There are enough tutorials on the Internet for this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! How do I get a table going in socket.io that just shows my variables?